# Get Coefficient of polynomial excluding variables

Tags: polynomials

I'd like to write a function that returns the coefficient of a polynomial, but excludes some 'cross-term' coefficients.

The function could be called CoefficientExclude, and the first argument would take a variable, then the second argument would be a list of variables to exclude.

So for `p` defined as `p=a1*x1 + a2*x1/y1+a2*y1`, this function would return:

`CoefficientExclude[p,{x1},{y1}] = a1`

`CoefficientExclude[p,{y1},{x1}] = a2`

`CoefficientExclude[p,{x1/y1},{}] = a2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `SeriesCoefficient`.

For example

```
p = a1*x1 + a2*x1/y1 + a2*y1
SeriesCoefficient[p, {x1, 0, n}, {y1, 0, m}]
```

gives

$\begin{cases}
 \text{a2} & (m=-1 \&\& n=1) || (m=1 \&\& n=0) \\
 0 & (m\neq -1 \&\& m\neq 0) || n\neq 1 \\
 \text{a1} & \text{True}
\end{cases}$

For a cross term both `m` and `n` will be nonzero. Avoid that condition and you are done.

In your case `[...,{x1^c},{y1}]` is equivalent to `m=c` and `n=0`

```
SeriesCoefficient[p, {x1, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, 0}]
```

Or say you explicitly want the coefficient of `x1/y1`, `(m=1,n=-1)`

```
SeriesCoefficient[p, {x1, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, -1}]
```

Comment: of course, thanks!